# Creating a simple X with CSS, but it doesn't line up?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple X-like cross in CSS, just two `<div>`s crossing each other at a 45 degree angle and meeting in the middle. I've tried to do it by creating a container `<div>` with dimensions 100x100 and two child `<div>`s, each the width of sqrt(100^2 + 100^2)  (using the Pythagorean theorem) and rotated to 45 degree angles.

The weird thing is that, at least in IE and Firefox, this doesn't result in a "perfect" X - the lines go noticeably further out on the right hand side than they do on the left.  Is there a reason for this?

See Codepen: http://codepen.io/matthewsot/pen/emJxaG

HTML:

```
<div class="hamburger">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}

@burger-height: 100px;
@burger-width: 100px;
.hamburger {
  position: relative;
  height: @burger-height;
  width: @burger-width;
}
  .hamburger div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;

    background-color: #fff;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }

  @hyp-length: sqrt(pow(@burger-height, 2) + pow(@burger-width, 2));
  .hamburger div:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0;
    width: @hyp-length;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .hamburger div:nth-child(2) {
    bottom:0;
    width: @hyp-length;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
```

Comment: you should use one of the answers below but the answer as to why they werent lining up is the lines were longer than the containing div so bottom: 0 was going to be off and similiarly for top

Comment: I think the problem is the thickness of the border. If you try to reduce the border to 1px, the X is correct. Probably, you should adjust the rotation to consider it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

It's caused by some margin on the left skewing the center point. It can be fixed by adding the following:

```
  .hamburger div {
       margin: -2.5px;
```

This appears to work because it seems there is an inherited property:

```
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 2.5px;
```

so by forcing the margin back `-2.5px` you are bypassing the inherited origin.

---

---

**HACKS BEFORE I FOUND THE SOLUTION:**

I did a little hack to line it up; all I did was change this line:

```
@hyp-length: sqrt(pow(@burger-height, 2) + pow(@burger-width, 2));
```

to this:

```
  @hyp-length: sqrt(pow(@burger-height, 1.95) + pow(@burger-width, 2));
```

So the full code:

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}

@burger-height: 100px;
@burger-width: 100px;
.hamburger {
  position: relative;
  height: @burger-height;
  width: @burger-width;
}
  .hamburger div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;

    background-color: #fff;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }

  @hyp-length: sqrt(pow(@burger-height, 1.95) + pow(@burger-width, 2));
  .hamburger div:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0;
    width: @hyp-length;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .hamburger div:nth-child(2) {
    bottom:0;
    width: @hyp-length;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
```

Was there something more you wanted to do, or did you just want to line it up?

---

p.s. Alternatively here is another hack:

I changed:

```
width: @hyp-length;
```

to

```
width: @hyp-length - 7;
```

so the full code:

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}

@burger-height: 100px;
@burger-width: 100px;
.hamburger {
  position: relative;
  height: @burger-height;
  width: @burger-width;
}
  .hamburger div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;

    background-color: #fff;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }

  @hyp-length: sqrt(pow(@burger-height, 2) + pow(@burger-width, 2));

  .hamburger div:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0;
    width: @hyp-length - 7;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .hamburger div:nth-child(2) {
    bottom:0;
    width: @hyp-length - 7;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
```

It seems the problem here is that the lines are longer than the cross section. The lines are defined by the length of `@hyp-length` in your code.

---

p.s.s. one last solution hack is changing:

```
@burger-width: 100px;
```

to

```
@burger-width: 90px;
```

Comment: That does seem to fix it, but would you happen to know why? Mathematically shouldn't the lines line up correctly as is?

Comment: i added two more solutions, but it seems to be something to do with the square root which you are using in the `@hyp-length`. Since you are using a square root, it is becoming an irrational number which skews the lengths from how it would otherwise logically seem to be.

Comment: Yep, seems like that "margin" is coming from the height of the div, thanks a bunch :D